# Give items to full height of container with height of 100%

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how do I make the *list items* of a container that has its height set to 100%, extend vertically to its full potential or until of the items have equalized vertically.

We have a side vertical bar right? Now inside that bar we have icons.
The icons are align vertically using  `display:flex; flex-flow:column;` By default the list items are on the upper most of the side bar.
[image: Here!]

Well I want the items(icons) to be full height so that its even vertically on the bar.
[image: Like this!]

**Basic code**

*html*

```
<!-- right bar -->
<div class="FullH">
  <section>
    <span class="Xm_flex-col" >
<!--   i want these to take as much space as posible vertically     -->
      <li>GF</li>
       <li>GF</li>
         <li>GF</li>
       <li>GF</li>
    </span>
  </section>
</div>
```

*Css*

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.FullH{
  height:100%;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  background:blue;
  padding:1rem;
  width:1rem;
    display:flex;
}
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.Xm_flex-col{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

**Site**

https://xlaeo.tk/XM_IG/projecthm/Xproject.html

Hope everything makes sense.

Comment: `height:100%` on all the nested container until you reach `xm_flex-col` ... then on it you use `justify-content:space-between`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)